# Tool for java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space , Java Swing Application

Tags: java, heap-memory

I am working with a Java Swing Application. I am getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. I am not able to figure out which method is creating many objects or if there are any not needed references. I want to figure out the root cause for the problem. Kindly guide me about any tool (JProfiler) for this issue. Also as I have not used this tool before so any added information regarding the same will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Krishna

Comment: Thanks every 1 for the help!!...I was able to get to the root cause without the use of profiler. There were large amount of data being fetched from the db which was causing the prob. Though thanks for the suggestions. I shall definitely try my hands on a profiler tool some time:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NetBeans IDE ships with a full featured profiler.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't already own a profiler, you might find JVisualVM useful. It ships with the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

jmap and the Eclipse Memory Analyzer Too1

[1]: http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ are a good combination